# Usage of spark.catalog.refreshTable(tablename) in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a CSV file after transforming my Spark data with a function. The obtained Spark dataframe after the transformation seems good, but when I want to write it into a CSV file, I have an error:

```
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

But I really don't understand how to use the `spark.catalog.refreshTable(tablename)` function. I try to use it between the transformation and the file writing, but it said

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

So I don't know how to deal with it...

```
#Create the function to resize the images and extract the features with mobilenetV2 model
def red_dim(width, height, nChannels, data):
    #Transform image data to tensorflow compatoble format
    images = []
    for i in range(height.shape[0]):
        x = np.ndarray(
                shape=(height[i], width[i], nChannels[i]),
                dtype=np.uint8,
                buffer=data[i],
                strides=(width[i] * nChannels[i], nChannels[i], 1))
        images.append(preprocess_input(x))
    #Resize images with the chosen size of the model
    images = np.array(tf.image.resize(images, [IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE]))

    #Load the model
    model = load_model('models')
    
    #Predict features for images
    preds = model.predict(images).reshape(len(width), 3 * 3 * 1280)
    
    #Return a pandas series with list of features for all images 
    return pd.Series(list(preds))

#Transform the function to a pandas udf function
#This allow to split the function in multiple chunks
red_dim_udf = pandas_udf(red_dim, returnType=ArrayType(DoubleType()))

#4 actions : 
#   apply the udf function defined just before
#   cast the array of features to a string so it can be written in a csv
#   select only the data that will be witten in the csv
#   write the data -> where the error occurs
results=df.withColumn("dim_red", red_dim_udf(col("image.width"), col("image.height"), \
                                             col("image.nChannels"), \
                                             col("image.data"))) \
          .withColumn("dim_red_string", lit(col("dim_red").cast("string")))
          .select("image.origin", 'dim_red_string')
          .repartition(5).write.csv(S3dir + '/results' + today)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a well-known issue where the underlying source data is getting updated while spark is processing on it.

I would suggest you to checkpoint i.e. move/copy the data to another directory before applying your transformations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help ! So, if I understand well, after the `red_dim_udf = pandas_udf(red_dim, returnType=ArrayType(DoubleType()))`, I move red_dim_udf to another folder of my S3 bucket, and after, I use the variable at this new folder as the entry of the following lines ?

Comment: (just adding some information :  I just don't understand how to move my Dataframe before the transformation, as 'df' is just a Spark Dataframe containing all my images in Spark format, 'results' is the Dataframe just contaning origin of images (as 'df') and features calculated from the function (so after transformation)... and I don't have other. How to I change the directory of 'df' (if I understand well) as this dataframe is only into the memory of the SparkContext (I think) ?

Comment: Just read and write to another directory using simple FS copy or using spark

Answer (score 1):

I think I can close my question, as I found the answer

If you have this type of error, it can also be because you have space in your S3 folders used to make your Dataframe, and Spark doesn't recognize the space character in the folder, so think the folder doesn't exist anymore...

But thanks @Constantine for your help !

Comment: Cool.. Good to know that there is this other reason for this spark error